# Regex max text after string, non-inclusive

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying get a text block between two tags and I'm having some difficulties. My sample text is this:

```
<file powershell>
Windows 6.3 Build 9600 
</file>
```

I'm trying to grab the text starting on the next line after `<file powershell>` and before `</file>`, using the tags as delimiters. Right now I'm using `^<file.+>\n` and `<\/file>` but that gives me the tags inclusively. I should only get `Windows 6.3 Build 9600`. Any help please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use capturing groups to capture the content you want. For instance:

```
<file.+?>(.*?)<\/file>
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vgaae4/2)**

Anyway, it seems you want to traverse an xml, if so you should use a xml parser or xpath expression like `//file/text()` or `//file[@powershell]/text()` assuming powershell is a well formatted attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use look arounds:

```
(?<=<file powershell>)[^<]*(?=<\/file>)
```

A look behind/ahead *asserts*, but does not *consume* input - ie it doesn't become part of the match.

`[^<]` simply gets around the problem of dot not matching newlines.

Comment: keep in mind that op is using variable `file` and look behind doesn't support variable length

Comment: @Fed sure, but OP is seeking fixed test: `"starting on the next line after <file powershell> and before </file>"`